# How to enable code folding for goclipse?

Tags: goclipse

Does anyone know how to enable code folding on goclipse?

The check box under `General->Editors->Structured Editors-> Enable folding` is already checked

I am using Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 and goclipse 0.16.1v201607061938.

Answer (score 0):

The Goclipse editor does not support folding, unfortunately.